# How can I search values with the same column name in multiple table in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I view values in from different tables but has the same column name in php through 'LIKE' or 'SEARCH' functions?

I have here 4 tables namely: mcertificate, bcertificate, dcertificate, gcertificate, and they all have a column which name is 'transaction_id'.

This is my query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT mcertificate.*, bcertificate.*, 
dcertificate.*, gcertificate.*, FROM mcertificate, bcertificate, 
dcertificate, gcertificate WHERE transaction_id LIKE '%$search%'");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: _“But there's an error on it.”_ - well then fix it …? If you need help with that, then at least mention what that error actually _is_ ... Please go read [ask].

Comment: wrt the deleted drawing question you may want to study [these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+doodle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is through the help of `UNION` :

```
select * from
(
  select 'mcertificate' as tbl, transaction_id from mcertificate union
  select 'bcertificate' as tbl, transaction_id from bcertificate union
  select 'dcertificate' as tbl, transaction_id from dcertificate union
  select 'gcertificate' as tbl, transaction_id from gcertificate
) tmp
where tmp.transaction_id like '%test%'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e9d7/5/0)

Comment: Wow it works, but I was wondering if what does the tmp does for?

Comment: it's a name of aggregated "virtual table". you can use whatever name you wish. With `union` you can glue results from several queries into one "virtual table" which later can be processed